# Using raw_input python to accept string with dash (-)?

Tags: arcpy

I have the following python input. The user will enter a value with a dash always. E.g. 2015-0001

```
Var1 = raw_input("Enter the number with dash: ")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("all_reports.gdb\\joined", "YearNo", Var1, "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

"YearNo" is a text field. If I do "print type(Var1)" it tells me that it is a string.

When I look at my YearNo field is shows 1972. It is doing a subtraction of the numbers rather than keeping a string together.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that CalculateField takes as the expression a string argument that is a python expression. The string is being evaluated inside CalculateField, so you need to encapsulate the value in quotes:

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management("all_reports.gdb\\joined", "YearNo", "'" + Var1 + "'", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

Comment: `"'{0}'".format(Var1)` would work as well, same principle from above.  [Format string syntax, 2.7.9](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Answer (score -1):

You raise an interesting point with this problem; almost a sort of semantic bug in the Field Calculator. The Field Calculator expression argument (Var1, a string) is being read in a sort of strictly literal way *as an expression* in the same way you'd expect to see an expression written in the Field Calculator GUI.

So, if we add str() to the expression argument we should get the desired effect:

```
Var1 = raw_input("Enter the number with dash: ")
arcpy.CalculateField_management("all_reports.gdb\\joined", "YearNo", str(Var1), "PYTHON_9.3", "")
```

Comment: No sorry that didn't work.

Comment: Whoops - sorry Andrew - go with Martin Wilkerson's answer, I'll pay more attention next time.